# Solve this exponential inequality

Tags: inequality

$$
{5}^{(x+2)}+{25}^{(x+1)}>750\\
t=5^{(x+1)}\\
t^2+5t-750>0\\
t^2+5t-750=0\\
$$

$$
a=1, b=5, c= -750\\
D=35+3000=3025 \\
t_1= 25; t_2=-30
$$

$t_1=25\Longrightarrow x=1; t_2=-30$ Doesn't have a solution
So the solution is $x>1$.
Is this correct? I say is bigger than $1$ and not smaller than $1$ because $1$(numer before $t^2$ is bigger than $0$. Is this reason correct or is it because $5>1$ so the exponential function is progressive (the bigger the $x$, the bigger the y)

Comment: $5*5^{x+2}\neq 25^{x+1}$, but $5*5^{x+2}=5^{x+3}$

Comment: $35+3000 \neq 3025$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$5^{(x+2)}  = 25 \cdot 5^x$$

$$25^{(x+1)} = 25 \cdot 25^x$$

$$750      = 25 \cdot 30$$

So your inequation may be expressed:

$$5^x + 25^x >30$$

As the derivative of $5^x + 25^x$ is always possitive, there is only one $x$ that makes the equality true:

$$x=1$$

And therefore, the solution of your inequation is $x>1$

Comment: Could you explain why is it x>1 , without using derivative. We haven't learnt them yet

Comment: The idea is that exponential functions (f(x) = a^x) become greater when x increases if a>1, so it is impossible that once you reach a determined value, 30 in your case, you reach it again. Furthermore, as it increases its value with x, the solution is x>=1 instead of x<=1

Answer (score 0):

$5^{x+2}=25^{\frac{x+2}{2}}$
so:
$$25^{\frac{x+2}{2}}+25^{x+1}>750$$
$$25^{\frac{x}{2}}+25^x>30$$
Let's say $25^{\frac{x}{2}}=y$
$$y+y^2=30$$
completing the square:
$$(y+0.5)^2>30.25$$
$$y>\sqrt{30.25}-0.5=5$$
remeber that $25^{\frac{x}{2}}=y$
$$25^{\frac{x}{2}}>5$$
square both sides:
$$25^x>25$$
this means $x\geq1$

Answer (score 0):

Go slower! First note that $25^x=(5^x)^2$ and set $t=5^x$. Then substitute:
$$
5^{x+2}=5^x\cdot 25=25t,
\qquad
25^{x+1}=25^x\cdot25=25t^2
$$
Thus the inequality becomes
$$
25t+25t^2>750
$$
and, simplifying,
$$
t^2+t-30>0
$$
or
$$
(t+6)(t-5)>0
$$